# What is ^ in Ruby Syntax? (Shopify scripts example)

Tags: ruby, shopify, editor

I am working on decoding a Shopify Script (for cart discounts) that was written by another dev and it includes some Ruby syntax I haven't seen before. Pulling up a google search there was no explanation I've found behind the use of "^" in the code below, specifically in these lines:

```
return @invert ^ ((@tags & customer_tags).length > 0)
return @invert ^ ((@tags & customer_tags).length > 0)
```

See context below:

```
  class CustomerTagQualifier < Qualifier
    def initialize(match_type, match_condition, tags)
      @match_condition = match_condition
      @invert = match_type == :does_not
      @tags = tags.map(&:downcase)
    end
  
    def match?(cart, selector = nil)
      return true if cart.customer.nil? && @invert
      return false if cart.customer.nil?
      customer_tags = cart.customer.tags.to_a.map(&:downcase)
      case @match_condition
        when :match
          return @invert ^ ((@tags & customer_tags).length > 0)
        else
          return @invert ^ partial_match(@match_condition, customer_tags, @tags)
      end
    end
  end
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks for any input

Comment: In such case, you first check the type of the left operand, than go to [this](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/) site and put a `^`  in the field _Methods_, to get the alternatives in the Ruby Core library. Of course you have to keep in mind, that every class can also provide its own definition of this operand.

Answer (score 4):

This is a boolean XOR operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: [`TrueClass#^`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/TrueClass.html#method-i-5E) and [`FalseClass#^`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/FalseClass.html#method-i-5E)

Comment: And with different meaning (depending on the left operand): [Integer#^](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#method-i-5E).

Comment: `Set` also has a [Set#^](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Set.html#method-i-5E)

Comment: @user1934428 Yes the following core classes define `#^`: `[Integer, FalseClass, TrueClass, NilClass, Set]` however in this case `@invert` *should* only be `false` or `true` based on `match_type == :does_not`. That being said technically any class could define `#^` or even `#==` to return anything you want but convention says `#==` should be equality thus returning `true` or `false` and standard implementation of `#^` in the core classes is XOR (be that bitwise, boolean, or an exclusive Set)